# Not being able to change the app icon in iOS using flutter launcher icon

Tags: ios, flutter

I tried to change the app icon from the package "https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons". I followed the steps written in the site and it did seem to have added the desired icons to the xcode. However the icon was like crashed when built. I came to realize that in xcode, in the assets, the target membership must be checked. So I did add the check mark in the target membership. This time it did read the icons in the xcode.

But i got another error, this time saying the following,

```
    error: Multiple commands produce '....../build/ios/Debug-dev-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Assets.car':
    1) Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has compile command with input '...../ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets'
    2) That command depends on command in Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
```

I have tried things written in the following site but with no results.

https://dev.to/kylefoo/xcode-12-new-build-system-warns-multiple-commands-produce-assets-car-56im

So can anybody please help me with it?

Answer (score 4):

Use Package: [`flutter_launcher_icons`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)

1. Setup the config file
   Add your Flutter Launcher Icons configuration to your `pubspec.yaml`

   ```
   dev_dependencies:
      flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.2"

   flutter_icons:
      android: "launcher_icon"
      ios: true
      image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
   ```
2. Run the following command in terminal:

   ```
   flutter pub get
   flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main -f pubspec.yaml
   ```
3. Run the package
   After setting up the configuration, all that is left to do is run the package.

   ```
   flutter pub get
   flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
   ```

Comment: Thank you Ayaz, but this was not the problem. The icon is actually already set on xcode. The package is working good but the while building its creating the problem